# TS2322: could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I know there are a bunch of questions answered related to this but I haven't been able to apply it here. I've distilled the problem down to the simplest form I could:

```js
interface X {
  x: null;
}

type WithX<T> = T extends X
  ? T // if already extending X don't extend again
  : T extends object
  ? XObject<T> // recursively extends objects
  : T; // leave basic values unchanged

type XObject<T> = { [K in keyof T]: WithX<T[K]> } & X;

interface Obj {
  a: string;
}

// Fails with generic. But WithX<T> should be assignable to T;
function f1<T extends Obj>(t: T): T {
  return t as XObject<T>;
  // TS2322: Type 'XObject<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  //   'XObject<T>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Obj'.
}

// Works fine without type mapping
function p1<T extends Obj>(t: T): T {
  return { ...t, x: null };
}

// Works fine without generic
function p2(t: Obj): Obj {
  return t as XObject<Obj>;
}
```

This is simplified but essentially highlights the problem which make no sense to me. I generally understand the whole explanation around not being able to assign `"foo"` to a generic of `T extends string`. But in this case we are only ever adding a property to T, so I would expect WithX to be assignable to T. And we can see that in fact it is assignable to it, just not when a generic is involved.

Is there any way for me to improve the typing so this works when a generic is involved?

Comment: Generic conditional types are essentially opaque to the compiler; it *defers* evaluation of them; in particular it does not try to "see into" `XObject<T>`  to determine that it's always assignable to `T`.  If you intend that to be true, you should write it directly like `type XObject<T> = T & (...)` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1EaKw), so the compiler can follow the logic (generic intersections are not deferred this way).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: The problem seems to be then it loses the ability to infer the recursive type when using array methods. I've built out the type a bit further to highlight [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJA1Dm). I don't know if is any way to have the best of both worlds here or not. If you remove the `T & ` then Array.map has the full type.

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/we6LgN)?  But we're kind of getting out of scope for the question as asked; could you either [edit] the original question to have enough use cases that it motivates a different answer, or maybe just leave it as-is, I'll write up the original intersection answer, and if you continue to have followups you post a new one?  Let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Brilliant I think that has made an improvement generally. I have some caveats in a couple of places where it produces a 'too complex union', but as you say I can create another question if necessary. Thanks so much, I've been beating my head on this one for a while :).